# to.period() does not work properly - trailing milliseconds

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, xts, zoo

I am trying to use to.period to convert milliseconds data into regular seconds level data - however the final output has trailing milliseconds

```
dput(head(x$Mid,20))
structure(c(3228.5, 3228.5, 3228.5, 3229, 3229, 3229, 3229.5, 
3229.5, 3229.5, 3229, 3229.5, 3229.5, 3229.5, 3230, 3228.5, 3231.5, 
3231, 3231, 3230, 3231), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(1543804206.41, 
1543804206.55, 1543804206.63, 1543804206.68, 1543804206.75, 1543804206.8, 
1543804206.85, 1543804206.93, 1543804206.97, 1543804207.03, 1543804207.07, 
1543804207.1, 1543804207.14, 1543804207.22, 1543804207.29, 1543804207.44, 
1543804207.7, 1543804207.75, 1543804207.88, 1543804207.93), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(20L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Mid"))


dput(to.period(head(x$Mid,20),"seconds"))
structure(c(3228.5, 3229, 3229.5, 3231.5, 3228.5, 3228.5, 3229.5, 
3231), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("head(x$Mid, 20).Open", 
"head(x$Mid, 20).High", "head(x$Mid, 20).Low", "head(x$Mid, 20).Close"
)), index = structure(c(1543804206.97, 1543804207.93), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

How to make the to.period output on timestamps round to the seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to.period` works with `endpoints` and using `to.period` in the way you are doing will take the last value of the second. `to.period` does not round the values. If you want that you could use the `round_date` or `floor_date` function from lubridate to get what you want.

A small example based on your x$MID:

```
t <- to.period(x, "seconds", OHLC = FALSE)
t
                          Mid
2018-12-03 03:30:06.97 3229.5
2018-12-03 03:30:07.93 3231.0

library(lubridate)
index(t) <- floor_date(index(t), "1s") # replace index with floor value

t
                       Mid
2018-12-03 03:30:06 3229.5
2018-12-03 03:30:07 3231.0
```